# Blockchain.info - Генерация кошельков и обход лимита в 20 неиспользуемых адресов

Tags: bitcoin, blockchain, blockchain.info

Нужно подключить оплату криптовалютой на сайте. Для этого у каждого пользователя будет возможность сгенерировать собственный кошелек, всего один, который будет привязан к его личному кабинету на сайте. После поиска информации решил остановиться на blockchain.info, так как у них простое Api и есть готовые библиотеки для этих задач.

По информации, которую я нашел - нет лимита на количество генерируемых адресов. Но я наткнулся на информацию о том, что может быть сгенерировано максимум 20 неиспользуемых адресов. Так называемый - Gap limit.

> Starting from August 1st, 2016, we will respond to API requests that would push you past the 20-address gap limit with an HTTP error, and we will not generate any new addresses for your xpub until we detect a payment that would close the gap below that limit. This ensures that you will never have unreachable funds through the use of Receive Payments API V2, but might lead to not generating addresses when your users request them.

Означает ли это, что если 20 пользователей подряд сгенерируют по кошельку, но так их и не пополнят, то лимит сработает, и возможность создавать кошельки приостановится? Если я понял правильно, как можно обойти данный лимит и будет ли достаточно привязать новые кошельки к новому xPub ключу?
Вот пример запроса на генерацию кошелька:
https://api.blockchain.info/v2/receive?xpub=$xpub&callback=$callback_url&key=$key&gap_limit=$gap_limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, это так. Но Вы можете генерировать адреса самостоятельно, например, используя [вот это](https://github.com/dryphp/bitcoin.php/blob/master/src/bitcoin.inc),

[или это](https://github.com/BitcoinPHP/BitcoinECDSA.php)

или [все, что угодно](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=generate%20bitcoin%20address&type=). И только после оплаты импортировать их в blockchain.info, а после обналичивания удалять.

Не уверен, что стоит привязывать адрес к учтной записи клиента. Каждый адрес лучше привязывать к отдельному платежу, чтобы проще было идентифицировать платеж